# Recyclerview inside another recyclerview adapter is not showing the item related items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android app.

There is a recyclerview that shows user messages, and there is another recyclerview in the adapter from first recyclerview that shows responses from users to the messages.

It is working but not as I want.

The responses shown at each message are not always the responses related to the message.

For example, at message #3, there are shown the responses to message #3, at message #2 there are shown the responses to message #3 and #2, at message #1 there are shown the responses to message #3, #2 and #1.

After refreshing the view, this can be different, the responses shown may be different.

This is the piece of code inside the adapter that manages the responses recyclerview;

```
 //respuestas

        holder.recyclerViewPosts.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        holder.recyclerViewPosts.setLayoutManager(holder.recyclerViewlayoutManager);

        subjectsList = new ArrayList<>();
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("origen", subjects.get(position).id_mensaje_chat);

        params.put("rnd", getSaltString());

        client.get(HTTP_JSON_URL, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
             @Override
             public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res) {
             // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
               Log.d("RES SUVJETC","respuesta chat "+res);
                 try {
                     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(res);

                      for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                         MensajesRespuestaChat GetDataAdapter2 = new MensajesRespuestaChat();
                         JSONObject json = null;
                           try {
                             json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        GetDataAdapter2.setid_respuesta(json.getString("id_respuesta"));
        GetDataAdapter2.setemisor(json.getString("emisor"));
        GetDataAdapter2.settexto(json.getString("texto"));
        GetDataAdapter2.setfecha(json.getString("fecha"));
        GetDataAdapter2.setorigen(json.getString("origen"));
        GetDataAdapter2.setnombre(json.getString("nombre"));
        GetDataAdapter2.setapellidos(json.getString("apellidos"));

                           } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                               }
                             subjectsList.add(GetDataAdapter2);
                          }
           recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewChatRespuestaCardViewAdapter(subjectsList, context);
                                holder.recyclerViewPosts.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);

                Integer num_mensajes = subjectsList.size();
                  if (num_mensajes == 0){

                     }
                   if (num_mensajes > 0){

                           }
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
               }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
      // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                       }
                 }
          );
```

Maybe you can find the reason for that issue there.

If you need further pieces of code, I can put them here, no problem.

Comment: Why you need two recyclerviews; just for different layouts to be displayed on left and right? You can handle different viewholder by type in onCreateViewHolder method.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, I am not sure if it is the best solution for my needs. I guess it should work at it is now, the only issue is to get the right responses at each message item. May be the issue is due to the use of the second adapter.

Comment: I see your goal can be achieved in single recyclerview, just you need to multiple view types. Check [this](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example) tutorial.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, I thank you for your advice, but would you mind telling me what is wrong in my approach to the problem?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, I will always need a second adapter to get options to manage the responses items, like delete them if needed